# outDebug does not exist! | FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When I try to run my flutter project on VsCode I was getting this error immediately:

- ..../linux/Debug/outDebug does not exist.

When I peep around my **launch.json** file I saw that there was lines which is not related to flutter project.

***You can see the answer I found below*** (in the answers section).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply delete the **launch.json** file and other unrelated files in **.vscode** folder. There is no danger to delete this file.

Because if u look inside those files you will see there is c/c++ related lines.